# How can I pattern match against exactly spaced names ?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a pattern for a name which can only include letters separated by single spaces if required? If there are multiple names, then they must be separated with a single space.

For example,
`"Jane Doe"` and `"Jane"` are correct but, `" Jane"` or `"Jane  "` or `"Jane   Doe"` are all incorrect.

My pattern,

```
/^([A-za-z]+ ?[A-za-z]+){1}$/
```

Comment: How can "Jane" and "Jane Doe" be both correct and incorrect?

Comment: What isn't working about your pattern?

Comment: @doublesharp His pattern doesn't work because he doesn't actually know what he wants.

Comment: @Rhyono that was my round-about way of asking what he wants :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i've understand you correctly, try this:

```
/^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)?$/
```

Comment: The regular expression needs to check the full alphabetic range: A-Z not A-z

Comment: What I mean to ask is that a name such as John Hopkins Derek Black must also be satisfied, which is not so in the given pattern. The above pattern will only resolve single and two worded names. If i change the pattern to, /^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+){0,}$/ will it solve the issue?

Comment: Yes. Note: instead {0,} you can use *

Comment: I'm afraid I can not help you, i have no win 8.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is not checking the full capital letter range (A-z must be A-Z)

NOTE: This is on the assumption that your question contains a typo and that in fact " Jane Doe" or "Jane Doe " is incorrect.

```
var patt=new RegExp(/^([A-Za-z]+ ?[A-Za-z]+){1}$/);
document.write(patt.test(" Jane Doe") + '<br/>'); --false
document.write(patt.test("Jane Doe") + '<br/>'); --true
document.write(patt.test(" Jane") + '<br/>'); -- false
document.write(patt.test("Doe ") + '<br/>'); -- false
document.write(patt.test("Doe") + '<br/>'); -- true
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FEycT/4/

Comment: If you using test, you don't need a braces "(" ")" and **{1}**.

Comment: Regexp space characters defines as **"\s"**

Comment: Please explain what you mean with not needing braces when doing a test?

Comment: Braces need make data extraction or combine chars into group. In this case you don't need make data extraction, cause you just checking. And you don't need for char group too, because **/^([A-Za-z]+ ?[A-Za-z]+){1}$/** is the same that **/^[A-Za-z]+ ?[A-Za-z]+$/**

Comment: Note: if you don't need to create regexp from string, create them directly.  It's faster: `var patt= /^([A-Za-z]+ ?[A-Za-z]+){1}$/`